# Heatmap corrected for population density

Tags: qgis

I would like to make something like a heatmap, but have it corrected for another factor, say population density.

For example, lets say I want to create a heatmap that displays whether or not somebody has a dog.  People in low population density areas are more likely to have a dog, but a basic heat map will make higher population areas look like they have more dogs just because there is a lot more people.

I would like to somehow make the heatmap take this factor into account so it shows a higher value for the # dogs by population density

Comment: Population density only makes sense with respect to an area with a defined boundary, but a heatmap typically does not have a boundary. Therefore you probably can't use a heatmap and still have a meaningful map. I think you should probably look at using a choropleth map, normalising your count of dog ownership with respect to population.

Answer (score 2):

There is a large body of [scientific literature on cluster detection](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ianturton/tag/clustering) which explains how to do this. One method used by Openshaw's GAM method is to calculate an overall expected rate of `totalobs/totalpop` and then for each observation point calculated the expected value as `expectedRate*pop` and compare that to the actual observed rate to.

I have an [old project](https://github.com/ianturton/spatial-cluster-detection/tree/e1d8401ba19998be9126d35397b5966c55ea4551) that has [code for this](https://github.com/ianturton/spatial-cluster-detection/blob/e1d8401ba19998be9126d35397b5966c55ea4551/cluster/src/main/java/org/geotools/clustering/AbstractClusterProcess.java#L84) and significance tests etc to create surfaces showing anomalies (not actual heatmaps but like that).